# Fill the table data where day is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a  table with data like below:

```
branch  day   amount   discount   gst
001     4     300.00   130.00     9.32
001     10    200.12   211.00     18.00
001     30    343.22   122.00     8.22
002     12    423.00   123.00     8.00
005     2     453.21   232.11     9.99
005     12    111.21   99.00      0.21
005     27    321.99   12.00      0.00
```

I want fill the missing day by insert the value into the table using vb.net to be like this

```
branch  day   amount   discount   gst
001     1     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     2     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     3     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     4     300.00   130.00     9.32
001     5     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     6     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     7     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     8     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     9     0.00     0.00       0.00
001     10    200.12   211.00     18.00
.......
```

The total days get from dayinmonth

UPDATE :

Im consider to do like this:

*select the table first order by day

```
jj = 1
while jj <> DaysInMonth(mth, yr)
if jj <> rowTable.item("day")
 * insert the value here.
jj = jj + 1
end if
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show us what you have tried? Basically you need to (a) search for missing days and then (b) insert the blank (?) missing rows. This is pretty much trivial to do in any programming language - give it a try and then seek help?

Comment: @svranken please refer my question.i already update it.

Comment: @robnick please refer my question.i already update it.

Comment: Your question is still incomplete. What's the highest value 'day' can have? You mention using DayInMonth but I see no other date info in your example that links these two.

Comment: @JanDoggen nvm, someone already posted the correct answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
declare @tab table(branch varchar(3), day int,  amount float) ;
insert into @tab values
('001',4,300.00),
('001',10,200.12),
('001',30,343.22),
('002',12,423.00),
('005',2,453.21),
('005',12,111.21),
('005',27,321.99);

with month_days as
(select t.number,t1.branch from (select number from master..spt_values where type='P' and number between 1 and 30) t cross join (select distinct branch from @tab)t1) 
select md.branch,number as day,isnull(amount,0) amount from @tab t right join month_days md on  t.day=md.number and t.branch=md.branch;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get missing days from the following query,

```
DECLARE @MIN INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
SELECT @MIN = MIN(dayField) + 1, @MAX = MAX(dayField) - 1 FROM YourTable
CREATE TABLE #TMP (FIELD_NO INT)
WHILE @MIN <= @MAX
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE dayField = @MIN)
      INSERT INTO #TMP (FIELD_NO) VALUES (@MIN)
   SET @MIN = @MIN + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #TMP
DROP TABLE #TMP
```

Now you can create INSERT Statement from the resultset.